# why can't i export geometry data from a shapefile?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, vector, export, csv

I saved the layer using "vector save as" box but even when adding GEOMETRY=AS_XY in the layer box, the csv only showed the id and no gemetry data.

Comment: What kind of data do you have: point, line or polygon?

Comment: a line layer.I used it to create cross sections from a raster layer.

Comment: How should all line node coordinates be squeezed into the attribute table? There is only one row for one line.

Comment: There's an option to save the geometry of the nodes.

Comment: `Geometry=as_XY` only works for point layers.

Comment: I also tried the line format:"as_wkt" but it does not extract geo data

Answer (score 1):

The `Geometry export to CSV` function of the `MMQGIS` plugin is the easiest way to get node and vertices coordinates of every vector layer.

Comment: I tried that but than I need to join the 2 files.
There's an easier way using "geometry=as_xy" but for some reason it doesn't work properly with my layer.
I updated to version 2.2 (Valmiera) but still it doesn't work and the csv file only shows me the id colum